# How to position correctly using background-image?

Tags: html, css

I want to use a custom underline for my h1 and I decided that the best way is to use the property: `background-image`.
Everything went well until I needed to position the background right under my `h1` (Ce e asta?).

I can move the image around the X axis but when I try to move it around the Y axis the image simply disappears.

Here's a capture

[image]

Searched the internet for an answer and to no avail.

```html
<div class="Title">
  <h1>Ce e asta?</h1>
  <div class="Paragraph">
    <p>Dat fiind faptul că următoarele alegeri parlamentare (legislative) vor avea loc de abia în anul 2021, m-am decis sa creez acest site pentru a ne putea alimenta cu speranță. <br>Speranță pe care ne-o vom dărui unul altuia. Ea va fi transmisă prin intermediul
      umorului, pentru că el de obicei reprezintă un înveliș pentru mesajul serios și intenționat care se află de fapt în spate. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.Title {
  margin: 75px;
  background-image: url("Images/Artboard 1.png");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: -500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Open sans", sans Cambria;
  font-size: 37px;
}

p {
  font-family: "Open sans", sans Cambria;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.Paragraph {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Comment: [`If you only specify one value, the other value will be 50%.`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)

Comment: Although what do you want isn't clear, i try to write possible solution. Check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to set the background on the `h1`, not for all the content. In this case, you can attach the background to the bottom of the `h1`. Obviously, it will be better to get a better quality image for that "border".

```css
body {
  background: #cccccc
}

.Title {
  margin: 75px;
}

h1 {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdcx0.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: "Open sans", sans Cambria;
  font-size: 37px;
  background-position: left bottom;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  background-size: 54% auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

p {
  font-family: "Open sans", sans Cambria;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.Paragraph {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Title">
  <h1>Ce e asta?</h1>
  <div class="Paragraph">
    <p>Dat fiind faptul că următoarele alegeri parlamentare (legislative) vor avea loc de abia în anul 2021, m-am decis sa creez acest site pentru a ne putea alimenta cu speranță. <br>Speranță pe care ne-o vom dărui unul altuia. Ea va fi transmisă prin intermediul
      umorului, pentru că el de obicei reprezintă un înveliș pentru mesajul serios și intenționat care se află de fapt în spate. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I was searching for. Unfortunately the problem persists even If i put the background-image under h1. My image is not showing up. I don't know how you managed to do that. The background appears only when I put in the property background-position: -200px and when I try to write the Y axis it suddenly dissapears.

Comment: I guess it's because we're not using the same image. Can you create a working snippet, jsbin, jsfiddle or codepen and use your actually content and image?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JgYqex here is the code. Here is the image I use https://imgur.com/a/GQqJjeR (you need to click on it to see the full image or you can save it)

Comment: Are you available? I'm still stuck.

Comment: Your image has dimensions of 1024X768 which is not fit to the `h1` tag. You can play with the css properties so it will show the image anyway: https://codepen.io/moshfeu/pen/jgBXNE. But I recommend that you'll adjust the image's dimensions so it will fit to the `h1`.

Answer (score 1):

You need background image under h1, so you need to define `background-image` in the `.Paragraph` class like this. This works, try it.

[Check Demo in Codepen](https://codepen.io/robin3317/pen/mNJaXv?editors=1100)

```
.Title{
  margin: 75px;
}
.Paragraph {
  margin-top: 25px;
  background-image: url("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/large-beautiful-drops-transparent-rain-260nw-668593321.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
h1{
  font-family: "Open sans", sans Cambria;
  font-size: 37px;
}
p{
  font-family: "Open sans", sans Cambria;
  font-size: 24px;    
}
```

Comment: Sorry If my question wasn't clear enough. I just want my background-image to be positioned under my h1 (Ce e asta?) so that it can resemble an underline.